# Angular build cannot find module with relative path (on azure dev ops)

Tags: angular, azure-devops

I have a problem getting a mid-sized Angular 7 project to build on Azure Dev Ops Pipelines. So I created a minimal project to recreate the issue.

Using Angular CLI (7.2.4) I created a new project

```
ng new minimal-app
```

It builds locally and on Azure just fine. I edited app.component.ts to use my UserModel, lines 2, 11 & 14

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {UserModel} from '../Models/User.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'minimal-app';
  user = new UserModel();

  constructor() {
    this.user.name = 'Jo';
  }

}
```

the User.model.ts file contains

```
export class UserModel {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

This also compiles on local and Azure just fine. The issue comes when trying to add a nested model, see Action.model.ts

```
export class ActionModel {
  id: number;
  datetime: string;
}
```

and changing the UserModel

```
import {ActionModel} from './Action.Model';

export class UserModel {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  actions: ActionModel[];
}
```

This works locally but on Azure Dev Ops I get

```
ERROR in src/Models/User.model.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module './Action.Model'.

##[error]Bash exited with code '1'
```

I've not changed any Angular config files, they are all default for new project. The azure pipelines yml is

```
# Node.js with Angular
# Build a Node.js project that uses Angular.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build --prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

Comment: Maybe try to add `.` to `./Action.Model` (`../Action.Model`)

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Sadly that doesn't help :( The models are in the same folder as each other though, so I guess it was a longshot, but I am confused with this

Comment: You can fix it when you try to build your application By using baseHref  AND deployUrl

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to your code, I notice that you are using **Ubuntu** agent which is case sensitive.

And also, the module you configured is "**Action.model**", but while import, the name you used is "**Action.Model**". For ubuntu and linux, it could not be identified as same because of its case sensitive.

I think you may execute these script locally with windows which is case insensitive. That's why it's worked locally.

So, for solved, you need to change your script as :

```
import {ActionModel} from './Action.model';

export class UserModel {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  actions: ActionModel[];
}
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks, and well spotted :)